# Bootstrap 3 labels: filling available space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootsrap, so this question might be trivial, but I'm having problem sizing labels.

Here is a simple code snippet:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="submit" value="<< Back" class="btn btn-danger btn-block"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <label class="label-info label col-xs-12">This label is too little!</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can find a working JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2446/

As you can see the `input` occupies the 3 columns it is assigned correctly and is also taller than the `label`. I'd like the `label` to:

- Be the same height as the button
- Fill up all the available horizontal space (the 9 columns it is assigned, as opposed to only filling up the space needed for the text, as it is doing now).

The behavior is correct for the button thanks to the `btn-block` class which makes it fill the available 3 columns, but there isn't an equivalent for the `label`.

How can I achieve this? It's probably really simple but I'm a noob at web stuff and bootstrap in particular, can anybody enlighten  me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base `.label` style won't allow that. My advice would be to define your own `.label-block` style which you can use in place of `label`. Something like this would work

```
.label-block {
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And then within your html, just use that style instead of `label`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="submit" value="<< Back" class="btn btn-danger btn-block"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <label class="label-info label-block">This label is too little!</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2447/) for reference.

Comment: Worked wonderfully, thanks! (I only had to adjust the paddings to match my theme). They should definitely implement the label-block class in the standard bootstrap, doesn't make sense having a grid system and not having a native way to fill the columns.